# Remove all files with name starting with single quote

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, rm

I need to delete all files with these names (the quotes are part of the name):

```
'index.html?some-query-string'
```

I tried with:

```
rm \'index.html?*\'
```

I get this error:

> ```
> rm: cannot remove ''\''index.html?*'\''': No such file or directory
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Analysis

> the quotes are part of the name

Are you sure? How do you know? There is this ["feature" of modern GNU `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/258679/108618), so it prints names with additional quotes, where there are characters like `?` inside; so when a total layman copy-pastes `'index.html?some-query-string'` and runs e.g. `rm 'index.html?some-query-string'` then this will be the right safe command.

Unfortunately this can confuse more savvy users who know they should quote/escape some characters. Your `rm` command (`rm \'index.html?*\'`) is fine for the name with quotes. It may match more filenames because of `?*` being a glob pattern; I assume this is what you want, as you wrote "I need to delete all files". The fact the command gave you `No such file or directory` makes me believe the existing name(s) are indeed different.

To confirm this, run `ls -N`. If this command succeeds and prints names like `index.html?some-query-string` *without quotes* then *these* are the real names.

---

#### Solution

This part of the answer assumes your `ls` is modern GNU `ls` or similarly "smart", so the quotes in question do not belong to the filename.

To remove a particular file, act as a total layman who sees `'index.html?some-query-string'` in the output of "smart" `ls`, or as a need-for-quoting-aware user (I believe you are) who sees `index.html?some-query-string` in the output of `ls -N`. Run:

```
rm 'index.html?some-query-string'
```

Or if you want to remove all files with names starting with `index.html?`:

```
rm 'index.html?'*
```

The shell will remove the quotes, they will not get to `rm`. The single-quoted `?` will not be treated as a wildcard, it will be passed to `rm` literally. The unquoted `*` will be treated as a wildcard, it will match any query string, the shell will pass possibly multiple matching filenames as arguments to `rm`.

Comment: About single quote on file name, `ll` comand returns:
`-rw-r--r--  1 root   root           2 Mar 20 13:25 'index.html?label=ecc'`

Answer (score 0):

If `'` is a part of name of your files, I'll recommend to use find command along with `" "` to pass the name pattern for your command.

An example which you can use is:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "'index.html?*'" -exec rm {} \;
```